# jquery plugin: use <b> or <div> to create blocks?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I put together a jQuery plugin that changes the aspect of the text in an HTML container and gives it an LCD-like appearance. Each character converted by the plugin is constructed with several square blocks ("bricks" as I've called them), absolutely positioned in a parent container - one container for each character converted. The bricks are in fact `<b>` tags with a `display: block` rule applied to them.

I've used them instead of `<div>` in order to reduce the amount of markup, but I want to know if there are downsides to this approach that I'm not aware of.
You can see the plugin in action here: **[Digitize](http://picselbocs.com/plugins/digitize/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes little difference, but perhaps a `div` or `span` would be more appropriate due to their lack of semantic meaning.

You aren't saving much here as the markup is built dynamically, so the length difference between `b` and `div` or `span` isn't significant in any way.

The HTML spec says:

> The b element represents a span of text to which attention is being
>   drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance
>   and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood, such as key
>   words in a document abstract, product names in a review, actionable
>   words in interactive text-driven software, or an article lede.
>
> The b element should be used as a last resort when no other element is
>   more appropriate. In particular, headings should use the h1 to h6
>   elements, stress emphasis should use the em element, importance should
>   be denoted with the strong element, and text marked or highlighted
>   should use the mark element.

But on the other hand, it really makes no difference when producing it using JS other than neatness. Twitter bootstrap horribly uses `i` for icons for instance!

The 'correct' way to do this by the way is to use the Shadow DOM – it's pretty brandspanking new, but it allows you to hide away implementation details in the same way that a `select` tag does (i.e. html just has `select` and `option` elements, but behind the scenes there is more going on).

For a demo, check out http://adobe.github.com/web-platform/samples/css-regions/shadow-dom/ in a new browser. If you use Chrome, then turn on Developer Tools Experiments in `chrome://flags/`, then in the inspector menu turn on the View Shadow DOM option. This will let you see what's happening here.

In short, you can make elements that are isolated from everything else and essentially invisible. You can style them as per usual, but can also isolate them from the rest of the CSS. They behave just like regular ones, except that they are not addressable in the normal way.

If I were making this plugin, I'd use Shadow Dom where I could, with a fallback to `span` or `b` or whatever, mainly just because cool stuff is cool!

Comment: I have to admit I've never heard of Shadow DOM, but it seems a bit TOO new to use, due to lack of support. Following the link you gave me using Chrome v20 returned this err: "No Shadow DOM support. Use Google Chrome Canary"

Comment: Oh yeah, it's new. Very new. Worth knowing about though – give it a year or two. Remember you can always use this to enhance your code, if desired whilst continuing with the normal method in older browsers. Plus, you'd likely be the first jQuery plugin to use this technology, making you officially awesome.

Comment: That'd be true, yes :)) Although I can't say I'm good at promoting it... so it'd be difficult to obtain official awesomeness even so.

Comment: Would you mind if I rewrote your plugin to use Shadow DOM where possible, then to write a blog post explaining how to do it? I'll link back to your site, and only talk about the changes needed, rather than examining the rest of the plugin. Also, I'm going on holiday for a week, so won't be for a while!

Comment: Well, I've been playing around, don't think this is really ready to use at all. I got it working OK, but can't clear the nodes as it seems that the methods that should exist don't. Well, sometimes they do, sometimes they don't! I won't publish anything unless you let me know it's OK btw.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in response, Rich, I was actually away on holiday myself. Yes, please go ahead with the plug-in, it's OK. Just a recommendation: make sure the article is as detailed as possible, because this is new technology. And don't forget to send me the link to it! :)